# Is it possible to predict how long a program will take to run?

Tags: performance, algorithm, time, execution

I was wondering, is it possible to do that with an arbitrary program? I heard that, with some mathematics, you can estimate how long a simple algorithm, like a sorting algorithm, will take to run; but what about more complex programs?

Once I visited a large cluster at an university, which runs programs from scientists all over the world. When I asked one of the engineers how they managed to schedule when each program will be run, he said that the researchers sent, with their programs, an estimative of how long they would take to run, based on the previous analysis that some program made for this purpose.

So, does this kind of program really exist? If not, how can I make a good estimative of the run time of my programs?

Comment: I ask because sometimes I just don't have a clue if my program will take 5 minutes, 1 hour or 1 month to end... And also because it is pretty interesting, of course :-P

Comment: Based on knowledge of what has to be done serially, and the run-time for each, you can estimate an overall run time. As far as automating the process goes, one of the early proofs of computer science what that you can't even be sure *if* it'll finish, not to mention how long it'll take.

Comment: You mean over a range of inputs? That's a subset of the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: @JerryCoffin that theorem was about about programs in general, not about an specific one. Which means that for many programs you can prove that it ends and in which time, but for some you can't. As long as you test one of the "bad" programs, everything is fine :-)

Comment: @SJuan76: yes, but his first sentence is: "I was wondering, is it possible to do that with an arbitrary program?"

Comment: Okay, I can't know much about an arbitrary program. But consider that I wrote some source code; are there techniques to make a rough estimative of the execution time? I mean, I would like to be able to say something like "this program will cost about O(n^2)"

Answer (score 9):

in general you cannot do this because in general you cannot prove that a program will finish at all.  this is known as the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Answer (score 7):

You're actually asking a few related questions at the same time, not just one single question.

Is there a Program A that, when given another **arbitrary** Program B as an input, provide an estimate of how long it will take Program B to run?  No.  Absolutely not.  You can't even devise a Program A that will tell you if an **arbitrary** Program B will ever stop.

That second version-- will Program B ever halt-- is called the Halting Problem, cleverly enough, and it's been proven that it's just not decidable.  Wikipedia has a nice web page, and the book *Goedel, Escher, Bach* is a very long, but very conversational and readable exposition of the ideas involved Goedel's Incompleteness Theorem, which is very closely related.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach

So if that's true, then how are the scientists coming up with those estimates?  Well, they don't have arbitrary programs, they have particular programs that they have written.  **Some** programs are undecidable, but not **all* programs are undecidable.  So, unless someone makes a serious error, the scientists aren't going to try to run a program that they haven't proven will stop.

Once they have proven that some program will stop, one of the major mathematical tools is called Big O notation.  At a very intuitive level, Big O notation helps to develop scaling laws for how the run-time of a program varies with the size of the input.  At a very trivial example, suppose your program is a loop, and the loop takes one arbitrary unit of time to run.  If you run the loop N times, it takes N units of time.  But, if that loop is itself in another loop that runs N times, the whole thing takes N*N units of time. Those two programs scale very differently.  (That's a trivial example, but real examples can get quite complicated.)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_oh

That's a rather abstract, mathematical tool.  Big O analyses are often so abstract that they simply assume that all sufficiently low level operations take "about" the same amount of time, and Big O doesn't really give answers in terms of seconds, hours, or days, anyway. In practice, real computers are also affected by hardware details, such as how long it takes to perform some very low level operation, or worse, how long it takes to move information from one part of the machine to another part which is extremely important on multi-processor computers.  So in practice, the insights from the Big O analyses are combined with a detailed knowledge of the machine that it will run on in order to come up with an estimate.

Answer (score 2):

You should research the Big O notation. While it does not give a fixed number, it tells you how its performance will change for different sizes. There are a few simple rules (if your code is in a loop of n iterations, then it will take n*time to run the loop).

The trouble are:

With complex programs there are multiple variables affecting it.

Does not take into account user interaction.

Same for network latency, etc.

So, this method works well for scientific programs, where the program is heavy calculus, using a very studied algorithm (and many times it is just running just the same algorithm over different data sets).

Answer (score 0):

You can't really.

For a simple algorithm you know if something is O(n) or O(n^2). Which one it is, you can guesstimate.

However, if you've got a program running tons of different algorithms, it'll become quite hard to guesstimate it. What you, however, can do, is predict results based on a previous run.

Assume you first estimate your program to run for one hour, but it runs for half an hour. If you change very little between builds/releases then you'll know next time that it will run somewhere around half an hour.

If you've made radical changes then it becomes harder to find the ETA :-]